# Is this setState({scale: 'c', temperature}) OK ?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

This demo code is from [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) , you could search this sentence on the page:

```html
this.setState({scale: 'c', temperature});
```

I thought the simply object {...} should has it's members form as key-value pair  , Why can this demo just have a value as a member of the object ?

Comment: When there is only the value, the key will automatically be the name of the variable, that is some es7 syntaxic sugar :) So in the end, you will have `{ scale: 'c', temperature: temperature }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With syntactic sugar on top of ES6 syntax, `this.setState({scale: 'c', temperature});` is treated as

```
this.setState({scale: 'c', temperature: temperature});
```

and hence it works as desired. This is an object property value shorthand syntax. You can read more about it **[here](https://ariya.io/2013/02/es6-and-object-literal-property-value-shorthand)**

Comment: THANKS ! Do you know how I can delete this duplicate quetion ?

Comment: @frontGirl, you need not delete the duplicate. Duplicate is helpful for SO to provide better search results